# Can't wipe SD card via diskutil or disk utility. Could it be broken?

Tags: disk-utility, sd-card

I am using a MicroSD card to program my Raspberry Pi with. I was recommended the `AEGO Micro SD Card 32GB Mini sd Card` card. However at this point I am wondering if I have broken it.

Here's what I have tried

- Disk Utility

  - First Aid on Generic Storage Device Media -> Operation successful
  - Repartition on Generic Storage Device Media -> Greyed Out
  - Erase on Generic Storage Device Media -> `A writable disk is required -69772`
  - First aid on system boot -> successful see results below
  - Erase on system boot -> it tries to unmount disk `Couldnt modify partion map -69874`
- Terminal

  - `diskutil erase` -> `(newfs). You cannot erase the boot disk. Ownership of the affected disk is required. Example: diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ UntitledUFS disk3`
  - `diskutil disableOwnership /dev/disk6` -> `Error encountered disabling user/group ownership: A disk with a mount point is required (-69854)`

Is there any way to recover from the state I got the SD in? Or is it potentially just broken now? How can I tell?
I have checked and the physical write lock is in the correct position.

Here is diskutil list

```
/dev/disk6 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *32.0 GB    disk6
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 system-boot             268.4 MB   disk6s1
   2:                      Linux                         31.7 GB    disk6s2
```

Here is the first aid on system boot

```
Running First Aid on “system-boot” (disk6s1)

Checking file system and repairing if necessary and if possible.
Volume was successfully unmounted.
Performing fsck_msdos -y /dev/rdisk6s1
** /dev/rdisk6s1 (NO WRITE)

** Phase 1 - Preparing FAT

** Phase 2 - Checking Directories

** Phase 3 - Checking for Orphan Clusters

430 files, 185612 KiB free (371225 clusters)

File system check exit code is 0.
Restoring the original state found as mounted.

Operation successful.
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you first format it? macOS can't read or write Linux ExtFS natively, you need a 3rd party add-in, Paragon etc. Note that First Aid only looked at the FAT partition.

Comment: I formatted it using Raspberry PI Imager. Unfortunately it will not let me do it again as it says it was write protected. I don't really care what is on this SD card right now. I would be down to wipe everything on it and start fresh.

Comment: If it won't format on anything, it's probably had a write error, which would push the firmware to lock itself protectively. This is, to all intents & purposes, irreversible. See http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only